# AWS dynamodb boto3 ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred when calling the PutItem operation:

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm new to AWS and DynamoDB, I'm trying to send data to a table.

I'm running this code:

```
import boto3

db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = db.Table('Whales')

table.put_item(
    Item={
        "id": "1573138502",
        "transaction_type": "transfer",
    })
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/---/Desktop/---/---/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    table.put_item(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resource not found
```

I installed boto3, I identified myself using the aws cli, I also tried running the code from AWS Cloud9 EC2 instead, but it didn't work, same error.

I have not been able to send anything to the db from Python, I don't understand where the problem comes from or what's causing it.

Comment: I would recommend checking if your dyanamoDB table is in the same region as the your connecting with AWS profile. You may have it in a separate region

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have the DynamoDB Table in a different region than the one specified in your `~/.aws/config`.

Try `cat ~/.aws/config` and check what region you are connecting with. ie `us-east-1`.

Verify that your DynamoDB is in the same region using the AWS Console or other CLI tools.

From what I see, your code should not by syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your aws region, sometimes lambdas made in some other region can't call DynamoDB of some other region and similar things happen in other aws services as well. To change region you can change link https://eu-north-1.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home?region=eu-north-1#dashboard directly change eu-north in URL link to ap-south and https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home?region=ap-south-1#dashboard then create your new aws services. This can be one of the reasons!